# Problem with calculating line intersections

Tags: python, math, pygame

I am trying to display the points of intersecting lines, but the calculated points are between the actual intersectings.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection)

I have checked the formulars multiple times and used another formula for calculating the intersecting points *x, y* `[x3+u*(x4-x3), y3+u*(y4-y3)]` instead of `[x1+t*(x2-x1), y1+t*(y2-y1)]`, but that just made the points somewhere really wrong

("d" is not referenced on the wikipedia page and is just the divisor for the formulars of t and u)

Function for calculating the intersection

```py
    def checkcol(self, startObs, endObs):
        x1, y1 = startObs
        x2, y2 = endObs
        x3, y3 = run.lamp
        x4, y4 = self.endpoint

        d = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)
        t = ((x1-x3)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y3)*(x3-x4))/d
        u = ((x1-x2)*(y1-y3)-(y1-y2)*(x1-x3))/d
        if 0 < t < 1 and 1 > u > 0:
            pygame.draw.circle(run.screen, pygame.Color('green'), (round(x1+t*(x2-x1)), round(y1+t*(y2-y1))), 3)
```

The whole code

```py
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random as rd

class Obs(object):
    def __init__(self, startp, endp):
        self.startp = startp
        self.endp = endp

    def drawww(self):
        pygame.draw.line(run.screen, pygame.Color('red'), (self.startp), (self.endp))
        for ray in run.lines:
            ray.checkcol(self.startp, self.endp)


class rays(object):
    def __init__(self, endpoint):
        self.width = 2
        self.endpoint = endpoint

    def draww(self):
        pygame.draw.line(run.screen, pygame.Color('white'), run.lamp, self.endpoint, 2)

    def moveEnd(self, xoff, yoff):
        self.endpoint[0] += xoff
        self.endpoint[1] += yoff

    def checkcol(self, startObs, endObs):
        x1, y1 = startObs
        x2, y2 = endObs
        x3, y3 = run.lamp
        x4, y4 = self.endpoint

        d = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)
        t = ((x1-x3)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y3)*(x3-x4))/d
        u = ((x1-x2)*(y1-y3)-(y1-y2)*(x1-x3))/d
        if 0 < t < 1 and 1 > u > 0:
            pygame.draw.circle(run.screen, pygame.Color('green'), (round(x1+t*(x2-x1)), round(y1+t*(y2-y1))), 3)


class Control(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.winw = 800
        self.winh = 800
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.winw, self.winh))
        self.fps = 60
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.lamp = [400, 400]
        self.lampr = 13
        self.lines = []
        self.r = 10
        self.Obs = [Obs((rd.randint(0, self.winw), rd.randint(0, self.winh)),
                        (rd.randint(0, self.winw), rd.randint(0, self.winh))) for i in range(5)]
        self.done = False

    def event_loop(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_F5:
                    self.__init__()

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0):
            self.lamp = (pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            for line in self.lines:
                line.moveEnd(pygame.mouse.get_rel()[0], pygame.mouse.get_rel()[1])


    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill((pygame.Color('black')))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, pygame.Color('white'), self.lamp, self.lampr)
        for line in self.lines:
            line.draww()
        for obs in self.Obs:
            obs.drawww()

    def createlines(self):
        self.lines.clear()
        for angle in range(0, 361, 9):
            self.lines.append(rays([self.lamp[0] + 1200 * math.cos(angle), self.lamp[1] + 1200 * math.sin(angle)]))

    def main_loop(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.event_loop()
            self.createlines()
            self.draw()
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            pygame.display.set_caption(f"Draw  FPS: {self.clock.get_fps()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = Control()
    run.main_loop()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Expected the points of intersecting to be at the actual points of intersection.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a lot of irrelevant code in your question. You would really improve it by removing the unnecessary parts, and providing some sample data with the corresponding expected vs wrong output. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: `u` is missing a `-` in front of it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I don't agree. The relevant (minimal) code is the small snippet in the middle of the question. And the large part is the complete application to verify the issue. It has to be minimal, complete **and verifiable**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the intersection points of 2 rays or line segments in two-dimensional space, I use vector arithmetic and the following algorithm:

[image]

```
P     ... point on the 1. line
R     ... direction of the 1. line

Q     ... point on the 2. line
S     ... direction of the 2. line

alpha ... angle between Q-P and R
beta  ... angle between R and S

gamma  =  180° - alpha - beta

h  =  | Q - P | * sin(alpha)
u  =  h / sin(beta)

t  = | Q - P | * sin(gamma) / sin(beta)

t  =  dot(Q-P, (S.y, -S.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, S)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))
u  =  dot(Q-P, (R.y, -R.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, R)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))

X  =  P + R * t  =  Q + S * u
```

See also [Line–line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)

If `t == 1`, then `X = P + R`. This can be used to assess whether the intersection is on a line segment.
If a line is defined through the 2 points `L1` and `L2`, it can be defined that `P = L1` and `R = L2-L1`. Therefore the point of intersection (`X`) lies on the line segment from `L1` to `L2` if `0 <= t <= 1`.
The same relation applies to `u` and `S`.

The following function implements the above algorithm using [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) objects of the [`pygame.math`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) module:

```py
def intersect_line_line_vec2(startObs, endObs, origin, endpoint):
    P = pygame.Vector2(startObs)
    R = (endObs - P)
    Q = pygame.Vector2(origin)
    S = (endpoint - Q)
    d = R.dot((S.y, -S.x))
    if d == 0:
        return None
    t = (Q-P).dot((S.y, -S.x)) / d 
    u = (Q-P).dot((R.y, -R.x)) / d
    if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1:
        X  =  P + R * t
        return (X.x, X.y)
    return None
```

The same algorithm without the use of the [`pygame.math`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) module, less readable but more or less the same:

```py
def intersect_line_line(P0, P1, Q0, Q1):  
    d = (P1[0]-P0[0]) * (Q1[1]-Q0[1]) + (P1[1]-P0[1]) * (Q0[0]-Q1[0]) 
    if d == 0:
        return None
    t = ((Q0[0]-P0[0]) * (Q1[1]-Q0[1]) + (Q0[1]-P0[1]) * (Q0[0]-Q1[0])) / d
    u = ((Q0[0]-P0[0]) * (P1[1]-P0[1]) + (Q0[1]-P0[1]) * (P0[0]-P1[0])) / d
    if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1:
        return P1[0] * t + P0[0] * (1-t), P1[1] * t + P0[1] * (1-t)
    return None
```

---

Applied to your code, this means:

```py
class rays(object):

    # [...]

    def checkcol(self, startObs, endObs):
        P = pygame.Vector2(startObs)
        R = (endObs - P).normalize()
        Q = pygame.Vector2(run.lamp)
        S = (self.endpoint - Q).normalize()
        d = R.dot((S.y, -S.x))
        if R.dot((S.y, -S.x)) == 0:
            return
        t  =  (Q-P).dot((S.y, -S.x)) / d
        u  =  (Q-P).dot((R.y, -R.x)) / d
        if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1:
            X = P + R * t
            pygame.draw.circle(run.screen, pygame.Color('green'), (round(X.x), round(X.y)), 3)
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-IntersectLines](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-IntersectLines#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math
import random

def intersect_line_line_vec2(startObs, endObs, origin, endpoint):
    P = pygame.Vector2(startObs)
    R = (endObs - P)
    Q = pygame.Vector2(origin)
    S = (endpoint - Q)
    d = R.dot((S.y, -S.x))
    if d == 0:
        return None
    t = (Q-P).dot((S.y, -S.x)) / d 
    u = (Q-P).dot((R.y, -R.x)) / d
    if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1:
        X  =  P + R * t
        return (X.x, X.y)
    return None

def intersect_line_line(P0, P1, Q0, Q1):  
    d = (P1[0]-P0[0]) * (Q1[1]-Q0[1]) + (P1[1]-P0[1]) * (Q0[0]-Q1[0]) 
    if d == 0:
        return None
    t = ((Q0[0]-P0[0]) * (Q1[1]-Q0[1]) + (Q0[1]-P0[1]) * (Q0[0]-Q1[0])) / d
    u = ((Q0[0]-P0[0]) * (P1[1]-P0[1]) + (Q0[1]-P0[1]) * (P0[0]-P1[0])) / d
    if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1:
        return P1[0] * t + P0[0] * (1-t), P1[1] * t + P0[1] * (1-t)
    return None

def createRays(center):
    return [(center[0] + 1200 * math.cos(angle), center[1] + 1200 * math.sin(angle)) for angle in range(0, 360, 10)]

def createObstacles(surface):
    w, h = surface.get_size()
    return [((random.randrange(w), random.randrange(h)), (random.randrange(w), random.randrange(h))) for _ in range(5)]

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

origin = window.get_rect().center
rays = createRays(origin)
obstacles = createObstacles(window)

move_center = True
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            obstacles = createObstacles(window) 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            move_center = not move_center

    if move_center:
        origin = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        rays = createRays(origin) 
        
    window.fill(0)
    for endpoint in rays:
        pygame.draw.line(window, (128, 128, 128), origin, endpoint)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), origin, 10)
    for start, end in obstacles:
        pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 0, 0), start, end)
        for endpoint in rays:
            pos = intersect_line_line(start, end, origin, endpoint)
            if pos:
                pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 255, 0), (round(pos[0]), round(pos[1])), 3)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```