# I'm having a problem with determining the intersection of two lines in this python code

Tags: python, math, pygame, geometry

I tried a math formula from analytic geometry but I didn't get the desired results.

As you can see in the code, the user draw two lines and a green circle(point of intersection) appear.

I have tried to fix the problem for hours but I failed. Sometimes the point doesn't appear or appear but in the wrong position.

[Source of the formula I used in the code](https://socratic.org/questions/how-can-you-find-the-intersection-of-two-lines)

[Docs of pygame the library I used](https://www.pygame.org/docs/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pygame import *
from time import sleep
init();
win = display.set_mode((500,500));
lines = []
cords = []
preview = False
xi = -100
yi = -100
def drawlines(flines):
    for fcords in flines:
        draw.line(win,(0,0,0),fcords[0],fcords[1],4)
while True:
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    for ev in event.get():
        if ev.type == QUIT:
            quit();
            exit();
        elif ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if ev.button == 1:
                preview = True
                a = mouse.get_pos()
                cords.append(mouse.get_pos())
        elif ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if ev.button == 1:
                cords.append(mouse.get_pos())
                lines.append((cords))
                cords = []
                preview = False
######################################## THIS BROKEN PART #################################
    if len(lines) == 2:
        #line 1
        points_line1 = lines[0]

        point1_line1 = points_line1[0]
        point2_line1 = points_line1[1]

        line1_vector = (point2_line1[0]-point1_line1[0],point2_line1[1]-point1_line1[1])
        a_line1 = line1_vector[1]
        b_line1 = -line1_vector[0]
        
        c_line1 = -((a_line1*point1_line1[0]) + (b_line1*point1_line1[1]))
        #line2
        points_line2 = lines[1]

        point1_line2 = points_line2[0]
        point2_line2 = points_line2[1]

        line2_vector = (point2_line2[0]-point1_line2[0],point2_line2[1]-point1_line2[1])
        
        a_line2 = line2_vector[1]
        b_line2 = -line2_vector[0]
        c_line2 = -((a_line2*point1_line2[0]) + (b_line2*point1_line2[1]))
        if (a_line2 != 0 and b_line2 != 0):
            if (a_line1 / a_line2) != ( b_line1/b_line2):
                #intersection between line1 and line2
                yi = ((((a_line1*c_line2) / a_line2) + c_line1) / -b_line1)
                xi = (((-b_line1*yi)-c_line1) / a_line1)
###########################################################################################
    elif preview:
        draw.line(win,(0,0,0),a,mouse.get_pos(),4)
    drawlines(lines)
    draw.circle(win,(0,200,0),(int(xi),int(yi)),10)
    display.flip()
```

Comment: Can you determine any patterns in the incorrect behaviour? Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. We can only help you with a problem that you have properly identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to dig through your code. Especially `c_line1 = -((a_line1*point1_line1[0]) + (b_line1*point1_line1[1]))` seems to be odd, because it  calculates the Dot product of vector and a point.
Therefore I don't know exactly what's wrong with your code, but I know how to intersect lines. See [Problem with calculating line intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312503/problem-with-calculating-line-intersections/56312654#56312654) and [Collision and Intersection - Line and line](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_collision_and_intesection.md#line-and-line).

Write functions that can add, subtract, scale vectors and rotate vectors by 90°. Write a function which calculates the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]

def sub(a, b):
    return a[0]-b[0], a[1]-b[1]

def rot90(v):
    return -v[1], v[0]

def mul(v, s):
    return v[0]*s, v[1]*s

def dot(a, b):
    return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1]
```

Calculate the vector from the beginning of the lines to the end of the lines and the normal vectors to the lines. The normal vector is obtained by rotating the line vector by 90°:

```py
#line 1
point1_line1, point2_line1 = lines[0]
line1_vector = sub(point2_line1, point1_line1)
line1_norml  = rot90(line1_vector)

#line2
point1_line2, point2_line2 = lines[1]
line2_vector = sub(point2_line2, point1_line2)
line2_norml  = rot90(line2_vector)
```

Calculate the intersection of the line segments. Make sure the lines are not parallel and that the intersection point is on the line segments:

```py
# vector from start point of line 2 to start point of line 1
l2p1_l1p1 = sub(point1_line1, point1_line2)

# intersection
d = dot(line2_vector, line1_norml)
if d != 0: # prallel lines
    t = dot(l2p1_l1p1, line1_norml) / d
    u = dot(l2p1_l1p1, line2_norml) / d
    if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1: # intersection on line segments
        xi, yi = add(point1_line2, mul(line2_vector, t))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
from pygame import *
init()
win = display.set_mode((500,500))
lines = []
cords = []
preview = False
xi, yi = -100, -100

def drawlines(flines):
    for fcords in flines:
        draw.line(win,(0,0,0),fcords[0],fcords[1],4)

def add(a, b):
    return a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]

def sub(a, b):
    return a[0]-b[0], a[1]-b[1]

def rot90(v):
    return -v[1], v[0]

def mul(v, s):
    return v[0]*s, v[1]*s

def dot(a, b):
    return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1]

run = True
while run:
    
    for ev in event.get():
        if ev.type == QUIT:
            run = False    
        elif ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if ev.button == 1:
                preview = True
                a = ev.pos
                cords.append(a)
        elif ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if ev.button == 1:
                cords.append(ev.pos)
                lines.append((cords))
                cords = []
                preview = False

    intersections = []
    for i, line1 in enumerate(lines):
        for line2 in lines[i+1:]:
            #line 1
            point1_line1, point2_line1 = line1
            line1_vector = sub(point2_line1, point1_line1)
            line1_norml  = rot90(line1_vector)
            
            #line2
            point1_line2, point2_line2 = line2
            line2_vector = sub(point2_line2, point1_line2)
            line2_norml  = rot90(line2_vector)

            # vector from start point of line 2 to start point of line 1
            l2p1_l1p1 = sub(point1_line1, point1_line2)

            # intersection
            d = dot(line2_vector, line1_norml)
            if d != 0: # prallel lines
                t = dot(l2p1_l1p1, line1_norml) / d
                u = dot(l2p1_l1p1, line2_norml) / d
                if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1: # intersection on line segments
                    xi, yi = add(point1_line2, mul(line2_vector, t))
                    intersections.append((xi, yi))

    win.fill((255,255,255))
    if len(cords) % 2 == 1:
        draw.line(win,(0,0,0), a, mouse.get_pos(), 4)
    drawlines(lines)
    for p in intersections:
        draw.circle(win, (0,200,0), (round(p[0]), round(p[1])), 10)
    display.flip()

quit()
exit()
```